# VBscipt date format

Tags: html, oracle, vbscript, asp-classic

This is my query.

```
 strSQL = "Select task,to_char(ddat,'dd/mm/yyyy') as ddat from task where guid = '"&lvGuid&"'"
        'Response.write strSQL
        objRS.Open strSQL, objConn

            If objRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
                strTask = objRS("task")
                strDate = objRS("ddat")
            Else
                strTask = ""
                strDate = ""
            End If
```

This is the form that show that i wanted to display a text area if the people is finish their task after due date for asking the reason. But the problem is the `if else statement` cannot be run. The program not display the `textarea` when the person is over due date.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="taskconfirm.asp" >

    <h2>Ticket : <input type="text" name="txtTask" value="<%=strTask%>" style="height:35px; font-size: 18pt; border:none;" readonly> </h2>

    <p>Today's Date: <%=Date()%></p>
    <p>Due Date: <%=strDate%></p>
    <p>By reaching to this link, you have completed the ticket above. Please click the button below to confirm</p>
    <br>
    <!-- ASP IF ELSE CONDITION HERE DATE - OVERDUE -->
        <%If Date() > strDate then %>
        <%response.write("Please give a reason for ticket overdue :")%><br/>
        <textarea type="text" name="txtreas" rows="4" cols="40" id="txtareaId"></textarea>
        <%end if%>
    <input type="submit" name="txtConfirm" value="Confirm" ">
    </form>
```

I feel appreciate for anyone trying to help.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the year comes last, VBScript interprets date literals as `mm/dd/yyyy`. Your SQL statement is formatting the date as `dd/mm/yyyy`, so it's going to get interpreted incorrectly (the months and days are going to get swapped).

For example, today is `August 12, 2015`. Your SQL statement is returning:

```
12/08/2015
```

But VBScript is seeing this date as `December 8, 2015`.

If you instead return the date as:

```
2015/08/12
```

Then VBScript won't be confused because the month always comes after the year when formatted with the year first (`yyyy/mm/dd`).